# Cast to ObjectId failed for value "6370d877cec3e8b947ab3dc3 " (type string) at path "_id" for model "Item"

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema, mongoose-web-server

I am trying to delete a document by clicking on a checkbox, i am able to get its id but i am not able to delete it by use of function FindByIdAndRemove()

```
app.post("/delete", function(req, res){
  const checkedItemId = req.body.checkbox

  Item.findByIdAndRemove(checkedItemId, function(err){
    if(!err){
      console.log("Successfully deleted")
    } else{
      console.log(err)
    }
  })
  
})
```

Comment: Is there an extra space in the string value after the `3` character? What if you `.trim()` the string?

Comment: thank you so much i dindnt realise that would make that  much of a difference